# How to share data at the php CLI clients?

Tags: class

*How to share data at the php CLI clients?*
I have create swoole WebSocket Server, it runs under CLI mode.
I want to save the socket info.

But each time the saved global variable has only the last client information.
*Is there a way to share data like $_SESSION in CLI mode?
I tried $_SERVER and $GLOBALS, but I couldn't do it.*

Answer (score 0):

$_GLOBALS not work on swoole,you can use Swoole\Table share data.
Before you create a Server, initialize table to store data that you wish to share.

```
<?php

class Server {
  public $table;

  public __construct() 
  {
    //initialize server code
    ...

    //initialize table
    $this->table = new Swoole\Table(1024);
    $this->table->column('name', Table::TYPE_STRING, 4);
    //other column
    $this->table->create();

    $this->table->set('user', ['name' => 'Bob']);

    //get user 
    $this->table->get('user');
  }
}
```